# Video Capturing in Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to capture the video on emulator with 2.1 sdk on windows. I am using Eclipse.  Is it possible to capture the video in the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible to use camera on emulator.

But you can set up camera on your computer to broadcast into network, and then connect in your Android app and get video.